# How to downgrade to Wine 4

Tags: 20.04, wine

I am running Ubuntu 20.04

HeidiSQL is not working with Wine 5.0. It appears to exist in a 0x0 window but I have no way to maximize it or view the content.

How do I remove Wine 5.0 and install Wine 4?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like [4.0.4 is still available](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/winehq-amd64/wine-stable_4.0.4~focal_amd64.deb.html). There’s a how-to about midway down the page 

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to install PlayOnLinux and then install HeidiSQL using its wizard:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Launch PlayOnLinux, click Install, enter HeidiSQL, continue the installation using wizard. It will install correct and tested Wine version for the application.

---

Links about HeidiSQL and its support status:

- https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=3326
- https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2651-HeidiSQL.html